# Sound Not Working on Ubuntu 20.04 Asus Vivobook Pro

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, asus, realtek, soundcard

Sound is not working on my Asus Vivobook Pro 14X (Ryzen 9 and NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX3050 STUDIO).

Speaker by harman/kardon;Chip: Realtek ALC294

---

```
cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c8000 irq 102

 1 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 103
```

---

```
uname -ro    
5.13.0-30-generic GNU/Linux
```

---

```
   *-cpu
        description: CPU
        product: AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX with Radeon Graphics

   *-multimedia:2
        description: Audio device
        product: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
        vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
        physical id: 0.6
        bus info: pci@0000:04:00.6
        version: 00
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
        configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
        resources: irq:103 memory:fc5c0000-fc5c7fff
```

Headphones are also not working.
Sound is working fine on Windows 11 in my dual booting system.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try the latest mainline kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research through the internet, I got a temporary solution to fix this issue.

```
sudo #!/bin/bash
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

Run this script then use the power button to shutdown your system(The normal power Off/restart/ with `sudo` privilege also didn't fix). I don't know how but this fixed my system. This will solve the issue until you boot to windows again, then you have to redo the process. I don't know if there is any other methods available to fix this issue permanently, but this is the only method that worked for me after trying multiple methods.

Comment: I have the same problem with a similar notebook, Vivobook m7400q. Ryzen and rtx3050ti
Your workaround works but it's unusable in the everyday work.
Did you find a more stable solution?
I'm struggling with this problem and every "solution" I tried didn't work.

Comment: (Unconfirmed) [link to the Bugzilla on this issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206289) from new contributor [@sf6](https://askubuntu.com/users/1655186/sf6) in an "answer" (that will likely be deleted as not-an-answer).  If a mod can convert that info to a comment on behalf of the user, I'll hope they'll delete mine at the same time ;-).  Or when @sf6 gains enough rep to leave a comment on their own, they are welcome to do so and Flag this/mine as "no longer needed".

Comment: Vivobook Pro 15 K3500PH, same ALC294 chip here. Even though this has "improved" the situation, I can effectively hear what people say, but it all sounds metallic, still low volume (compared to what I heard with the windows drivers in the beginning) and if the sound has been over-amplified.
Plenty people seem to post different values for the hda-verb command but nobody explains what exactly they do or stand for.