# No audio on ASUS VIVOBOOK M7400Q with realtek ALC294

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I've just bought a new asus vivobook m7400qe (ryzen, nvidia rtx, 16gb ram, etc), with the onboard notorius REALTEK ALC294 audio chipset

Setup:
dual boot with windows 11 pro and ubuntu 22.04 (I need both).

Installed windows and everything is fine.
Installed ubuntu and everything is fine EXCEPT the audio:

- mic works correctly
- NO AUDIO FROM ONBOARD SPEAKERS and neither from the headphones jack.
  If I connect the headphone jack I hear some cracks an bumps but no audio at all.

The audio output is recognized as "speakers: family 17h (models 10h-1fh) HD audio controller"

I'm working on this problem in the last 4 days without any success.
I've read hundreds of workarounds, guides, bug reports etc, tried everything I found but with no success at all.

The ONLY workaround that worked is this, but with a HUGE "but":
[Sound Not Working on Ubuntu 20.04 Asus Vivobook Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394452/sound-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-asus-vivobook-pro)

> After a lot of research through the internet, I got a temporary
> solution to fix this issue.
>
> sudo #!/bin/bash
> sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
> sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
> sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
> sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
>
> Run this script then use the power button to shutdown your system(The
> normal power Off/restart/ with sudo privilege also didn't fix). I
> don't know how but this fixed my system. This will solve the issue
> until you boot to windows again, then you have to redo the process. I
> don't know if there is any other methods available to fix this issue
> permanently, but this is the only method that worked for me after
> trying multiple methods.

Trying this, at the next boot audio works but if I boot on windows, and then to ubuntu again, the audio is gone again, as the guy says in the link that I quoted.
I tried putting the script in crontab (even root's crontab), to execute at every boot but if a boot to windows is involved, then still no audio on ubuntu next time.
Other quirk thing is that sometime, when I boot to windows, audio is broken there too and I need to reinstall the realtek drivers there.

Also disabled fastboot (both on windows AND bios), but no luck. Tried reinstalling alsa, pulseaudio, resetting all. Nothing.

I'm desperate, I need this to work, it's a notebook that was given to me from my employer and I have to keep this one. No way he would change it with another model.

here some useful info:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c8000 irq 87
 1 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc5c0000 irq 88
$ aplay -l
**** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
scheda 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], dispositivo 0: ALC294 Analog [ALC294 Analog]
  Sottoperiferiche: 0/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0

$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: nbced04 Kernel: 5.15.0-43-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.2
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: Vivobook_ASUSLaptop M7400QE_M7400QE
    v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: M7400QE v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: M7400QE.307 date: 03/07/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor driver: N/A
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-43-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my brand new laptop Asus Vivobook Pro 14x with the same audio chipset ALC294 and I did struggle to find an answer.

I found a solution on internet and it worked for me:

you will need to create a bash file and execute it in root mode:

```
sudo #!/bin/bash

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

The original code is not from me, I took it from the link bellow. The I put it into a bash file to make it more simple to use.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1394625/1628848

Comment: same system configuration, same problem, but the solution above still does not fix it for me :( any alternative? update: it worked for me just by running the first two commands and NOT the last two: sudo #!/usr/bin/bash sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with my Asus Vivobook 14X Pro OLED and found the solution Slightly different than other solutions on the internet.

Make a bash script file and include this in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

Then save it, make it executable, and run it, then reboot and the Audio will be fixed. Further, it's just a temporary solution and it reverts back to original once you boot to Windows and come back to your Linux distro. In that case, just execute it again and reboot and it'll be fixed again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue ASUS Vivobook pro 15 oled (k6500, 12th gen intel )

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

Use Cron for use this script on each boot:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and write to end of file:

```
@reboot sleep 5 && /absolute/path/to/script.sh
```

I use `sleep` because `/dev/snd/hwC1D0` file created after Cron reboot tasks...
I hope this info help someone!

**UPD**:

After reinstall UBUNTU this script does not fix problem anymore. Instead I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x400 0x7774
```

Comment: After reinstalling Ubuntu it doesn't work anymore