# How to undo hda-verb change?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I was trying to set up Ubuntu 20.04.5 dual booting with Windows 11 home edition. After I solved the Nvidia driver problem, my speaker sound disappear. pavucontrol shows that the speaker is still outputting.

I literally have the same problem with this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420976/no-audio-on-asus-vivobook-m7400q-with-realtek-alc294), but after I use the bash file with cmd:

```
sudo #!/bin/bash

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf

sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

Then I went to windows, and not surprisingly, broken sound; so I uninstall the windows ReakTek driver and reboot.
Normally, windows will install the driver for me, and the sound will work fine in windows again.
But I could not hear the sound even after it installs the driver for me.

So I was trying to undo the change made in the hda-verb, but I cannot find a source about how to undo the change.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[Edit]: My goal is try to undo the effect this bash does to my computer.
From the link: programmersought.com/article/9581893187 I try to look up the parameter the bash file uses, but all the examples are how to set the value, but not back to the default value. For example, The cmd: hda-verb 0x19 SET_PIN_WIDGET_CONTROL 0x24 Set the node 0x19 parameter to SET_PIN_WIDGET_CONTROL with a value of 0x24. Then how can I set the node 0x19 to its original mode and original value?

Comment: is the problem in Windows or Ubuntu? Very unclear, but if the issue is with Windows then this question is off-topic here.

Comment: also if the sound doesn't work in either Windows or Ubuntu, it is possible this is a hardware issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of desperate here to find answers so I did not make it clear. I want to undo the change that the bash command did to my computer.

Comment: https://www.programmersought.com/article/9581893187/
I try to look up the parameter the bash file uses, but all the examples are how to set the value, but not back to the default value.
For example, 
The cmd: hda-verb 0x19 SET_PIN_WIDGET_CONTROL 0x24
Set the node 0x19 parameter to SET_PIN_WIDGET_CONTROL with a value of 0x24.
Then how can I set the node 0x19 to its original mode and original value?

Comment: well you can find out what the original value was, and set it to that.