# No sound with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on Asus Zenbook UX582L

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my new Asus Zenbook (single install not dual-boot)
No sound comes out from the speakers, or the headphones jack (while in Windows sound is ok).

I previously tried with Kali-Linux and it didn't work either. For several days I browsed similar "no sound questions", but it didn't work out. So now I freshly re-installed ubuntu 22.04.2, updated it, and installed pavucontrol, and inxi only for a fresh start.

Hoping someone can help I put some useful information below.

Thanks,

`uname -a`

`LINUX username 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`alsamixer`

```
| Card: HDA Intel PCH
│ Chip: Realtek ALC294
│ View: Playback 
│ Item: Master
```

Everything is on, "OO", Auto-Mute is disabled

`inxi -SMAG`

```
System:
  Host: Username Kernel: 5.19.0-46-generic x86_64
    bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.5
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK
    product: ZenBook Pro Duo UX582LR_UX582LR v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UX582LR v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends
    v: UX582LR.305 date: 12/30/2021
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
    driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: nvidia v: 535.54.03
  Device-3: USB C Video Adaptor type: USB driver: N/A
  Device-4: IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa
    gpu: i915 resolution: 1: 3840x1100~60Hz
    2: 1680x1050~60Hz 3: 3840x2160~60Hz
  OpenGL:
    renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.54.03
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA104 High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-46-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

`pavucontrol`

```
Output devices: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
Port: Speakers (on which I can see the audio bar moving when playing a youtube video)
Configuration: Analog Stereo Duplex/Analog Stereo Output (same thing)
```

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-zenbook
```

`alsa-info` (scanned alsa-info)

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=76a4508f951d475f28e92f6e5f1bf5f211d420aa

`sudo dmesg | grep -E 'snd|firmware|audio'`

```
[    2.587276] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.593199] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.595224] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
[    2.602793] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    2.602936] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.603208] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.603290] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    2.603299] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    2.998297] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    4.262328] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    5.178134] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.310376] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC294: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.310380] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.310382] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.310384] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.310385] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    5.310386] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x13
[    5.310387] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
```

Comment: Are there any related errors in dmesg? `sudo dmesg | grep 'snd|firmware|audio'`

Comment: @SamO'Riil No Error it just execute the command with no error and no info

Comment: Sorry, there's a mistake, it should be like `sudo dmesg | grep -E 'snd|firmware|audio'` It can't be empty if all is OK.

Comment: @SamO'Riil Please Check i have updated the output ^

Comment: @crazymhedge Thank you. Yes, no issues here. So the only thing to try I can suggest is to switch `asus-zenbook` to `auto` in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and make sure `Fast boot` is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Also you can try black magic aka hda-verb like written here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420976/no-audio-on-asus-vivobook-m7400q-with-realtek-alc294

Comment: @SamO'Riil I tried your suggestion and hda-verb both are not working

Comment: @SamO'Riil i tried using headphone but no luck both headphone and speakers are not working

Comment: Somehow i fixed the problem by updating the kernal to 6.4.3 generic after updating the kernal `sudo apt update` and `reboot` worked

Comment: If it holds, I guess it would be right to post this as an accepted answer to help someone else with this problem. After all 6.4 kernel is not something normal for 22.04...

Answer (score 0):

This forum post https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2488400#post_14150108 suggests that upgrading to the latest 6.4.x (or later) kernel may fix the problem.

Ubuntu 23.10 includes the 6.5.x series kernel, so upgrading your Ubuntu version using:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

is likely to solve the problem.

Alternatively, [these instructions](https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-install-linux-kernel-6-4-on-ubuntu-heres-how) describe how to install a later (but not officially supported) kernel on 22.04